# JQuery test failed...need solution

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I did everything mentioned on http://volaresystems.com/Blog/post/Autocomplete-dropdown-with-jQuery-UI-and-MVC.aspx
 but i got nothing when i type a-z in my textbox

My form

```
<%using (Html.BeginForm("")) %>
<%:Html.TextBox("completeMe","name") %>
<%:Html.TextBox("completeMe","ID") %>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
<%} %>
```

Assemblies

```
<link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" />
<link href="../../Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: You can't just point to a correct implementation and say you've done all that. *Obviously* something is different if their version is working, and yours isn't. Show us your complete code, and perhaps more importantly, tell us about your errors: when they're happening, and what the exact error message is.

Comment: Yes you are right David. I am trying to upload my code here//but not able to fomat it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I did everything mentioned on
>   http://volaresystems.com/Blog/post/Autocomplete-dropdown-with-jQuery-UI-and-MVC.aspx

I can't see many things in common between the script inclusions you did and the ones mentioned in the article. You have included the jquery UI twice. Also you hardcoded your urls instead of using url helpers as shown in the article. Also you are using different versions of jquery and jQuery UI so make sure those scripts are available in your scripts folder. So try the following:

```
<link href="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css") %>" />
<link href="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css") %>" type="text/css" />

<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then open up your javascript debugging tool in your browser and look if you don't get some javascript errors, wrong url paths, ...